# iOS:UIPopoverController won't release after it shows

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom view that implements `UIView`, the view has a *instance variable* to hold a `UIPopoverController`. It is OK if I dont call the `[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:btn.frame inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];`
the custom view will call **dealloc**. But when I call that method, the custom view ***won't*** call the **dealloc**. Why? How can I fix this? Is this *memory leak*?

PS: I run the code under **ARC** mode.

Please help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Was the popover dismissed?

Comment: Are you setting `popoverController` to `nil` in `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:`?  Does `popoverController` have a strong reference to your view?

Comment: Please show methods and declarations.